# Using the variable "default"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a way I can use the variable `default` as an argument?

I'm essentially being passed a prop named `default` from a json file but whenever I try to reference it, it errors out (because it's a reserved word I think)

Is there a workaround for this?

```
json = { default: 0, type: number } // passed into my function

const func = ({default, type}) => { // "default" is a reserved word
    console.log(default)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should add the relevant code as a [mcve].

Comment: @Andy added an example of what I'm trying to do

Comment: It's a reserved word, so you can't use it as a variable name. But it should be ok as an object property, so I'm not sure why `this.props.default` wouldn't be allowed. (Unless it's something specific to React.) [Just seen the example: yeah you can't do that. Just give it a different name, which you'll have to do "longhand".]

Comment: `const func = ({ default: defaultValue, type}) => {
    console.log(defaultValue)
}`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks! That solved it :-). I can check your answer if you post it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the parameter when you pass it to the function:

```js
const json = { default: 0, type: 'number' };

const func = ({ default: newDefault, type }) => {
  console.log(newDefault, type);
}

func(json);
```

See: object destructuring [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) & [2](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)

Comment: Dude, it's Dr. Axel Rauschmayer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the whole json -object as an argument and refer to object's field:

```
json = { default: 0, type: number } // passed into my function

const func = (json) => { 
   const myTrickyValue = json['default'];
   console.log(myTrickyValue);
}
```